# Using result transformer in mongodb criteria

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

We're using MongoDB in our Grails 2.3.5 app without hibernate. Is there any way to use `resultTransformer` to convert property projection as `Map` like in hibernate.

For example:

```
  User.withCriteria {
        resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
        projections {
            property('name', 'fullName')
        }
        def now = new Date()
        between('joinDate', now-365, now)
  }
```

This works in hibernate. Is this supported in Grails MongoDB or have some alternative to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a ResultTransformer is a Hibernate specific API so cannot be used. You can write a general PostQuery event listener (see http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/query/event/PostQueryEvent.html) that can transform the results and register a listener (http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/engine/event/AbstractPersistenceEventListener.html)

But this is a general approach and not really to be done a per query basis

Comment: What do mean by **not really to be done a per query basis**. Can you please explain a bit more. Is this cause a performance hit if used for a domain class.?

Comment: What I mean is when you add a query listener as per above it is added globally *to all queries* in your application

Comment: Oh, I got it. Will have to try something different.